# Grails read from existing DB

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-plugin, grails-domain-class, grails-controller

I want to fetch data from already existing database from another project into my Grails project and list the data.  Should I be creating a domain controller for the already existing db?  I know how to create domain-controller and use data migration plugin to update db but none of the books I read had any information on how to setup and read from an existing database. I'm using MySQL for my database.

Comment: Don't you think posting the existing table schema might help?

Comment: I haven't started one. Reguardless of the schema, I'm trying to access one table from another database. Say devDb.tblUsers

Comment: What is meant by "existing database from another project"? The main question lies here is whether you have the domain classes for the underlying tables accessible to you or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Reverse Engineer plugin to create domain classes from your existing database: https://plugins.grails.org/plugin/grails/db-reverse-engineer

Comment: Thanks Burt, this will really help me out. I'm evaluating Grails for our Corporation as possible replacement for PHP dev. I use your book Programming Grails for reference. Do you have any other books you recommend? Also, is it not possible to access data from database without a domain class like in php mysqli?

Answer (score 3):

As per my understandings, please do the following :

Suppose you have an existing DB "TestDB" with a table "domain_model" and it has columns "column_a", "column_b" and "column_c".

In Grail, create one domain Class and add the following in mapping block :

```
static mapping = {
    table "domain_model"
            version false
            id column: "primary_key_column"
            columnA column: "column_a"
            columnB column: "column_b"
            columnC column: "column_c"
}
     String id
     String columnA
     Date columnB
     Integer columnC
```

and in DataSource.groovy, keep dbCreate property to be set as "update".

dbCreate="update"

Hope this helps !

Also, make sure to add "id" and "version" column to your existing table where "id" column is autoincremented, and you can have "version" column as "1" to all records.

Comment: Thanks. An additional question, can Grails read xml as a data source?

Answer (score 1):

@codeBarer You can use xml as a datasource in Grails by putting the xml file in `grails-app/conf`. You can reference this file in `BootStrap.groovy` with:

```
class.getResource("yourData.xml")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def defaultDataFileStream = this.class.getResourceAsStream("defaultData.xml")
def allData = new XmlSlurper().parse(defaultDataFileStream)
```

Try this in `bootstrap.groovy`. You'll put the xml file in `grails-app/conf`.

Answer (score 0):

for creating domain classes you can use [GARG]:http://grag.sourceforge.net/index.html

Comment: I tried using GARG but since the schema I want to export has over 800 tables. The program throws exceptions and runs out of memory before it's done creating the objects